# Statsd and InfluxDB: how to handle host information?

Tags: statsd, influxdb, grafana

I want to measure statsd performance metrics in a couple of applications on a couple of hosts. Those measurements will be aggregated by statsd, then stored in influxdb and then visualized in grafana. The architecture will be very similar to the one shown in this blog post: http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/metrics-cocktail-statsdinfluxdbgrafana

App -> Statsd -> InfluxDB -> Grafana

My application 'app1' runs on host1, host2, host3 in environment 'prod'.

So my statsd metrics names as sent from app1 in prod would be:

```
prod.app1.host1.load_customer
prod.app1.host2.load_customer
prod.app1.host3.load_customer
```

In grafana in prod I would then see three different metrics for the same thing, but I really want to see only one metric called prod.app1.load_customer that aggregates over all three hosts of the prod environment. I would like to be able to drill into a certain host if needed, however.

I think this should be a pretty common problem for users of this toolchain so I guess some people must have solved it?

I'm using influxdb-0.9.3-1, writing to it via API calls.

Comment: Which version of InfluxDB are you running? Are you writing through a plugin or direct API calls?

Comment: Have you checked out https://influxdb.com/chronograf/index.html ?